# if statements returning true and not going over all of my if statements - javascript

Tags: javascript

Hi all my code works great when tested one by one but when i insert them all together if the first IF statement is reached it will return true and submit the form without validating the others.. can someone tell me how to change my code around so it will run all the IF statements before it returns true.

Here is my code

```
    if (this.element.find('#visitdate').length > 0) {
    var dateParts = $('#tvisitdate').val().split('/');
    var check = new Date(dateParts[2], dateParts[1]-1, dateParts[0], 0,0,0,0);
    var d = new Date();
    var today = new Date(d.getFullYear(), d.getMonth(), d.getDate());

    if (today.getTime() > check.getTime() ) {
        _errMsg = "Please enter a future visit date";
        return false;
    } else {
        return true;
    }
}

if (this.element.find('#birthdate').length > 0) {
    var dateParts1 = $('#birthdate').val().split('/');
    var check1 = new Date(dateParts1[2], dateParts1[1]-1, dateParts1[0], 0,0,0,0).getFullYear();
    var today1 = new Date();
    var year = today1.getFullYear();

    if (check1 >= year) {
        _errMsg = "Please enter a valid date of birthday";
        return false;
    } else {
        return true;
    }
}
```

Comment: Indent the code, and the solution will appear.

Comment: Can you give me a example with my code...

Comment: basic `if` usage...  your first nested if is returning true or false, thus exiting before the second nested if.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a boolean (true/false) variable and then return that variable at the end of the code. This way you only have one return statement:

```
var check_no_error = true;
if (this.element.find('#visitdate').length > 0) {
    var dateParts = $('#tvisitdate').val().split('/');
    var check = new Date(dateParts[2], dateParts[1]-1, dateParts[0], 0,0,0,0);
    var d = new Date();
    var today = new Date(d.getFullYear(), d.getMonth(), d.getDate());

    if (today.getTime() > check.getTime() ) {
        _errMsg = "Please enter a future visit date";
        check_no_error = false;
    }
}

if (this.element.find('#birthdate').length > 0) {
    var dateParts1 = $('#birthdate').val().split('/');
    var check1 = new Date(dateParts1[2], dateParts1[1]-1, dateParts1[0], 0,0,0,0).getFullYear();
    var today1 = new Date();
    var year = today1.getFullYear();

    if (check1 >= year) {
        _errMsg = "Please enter a valid date of birthday";
        check_no_error = false;
    }
}
return check_no_error;
```

Answer (score 0):

you should `not use return for each if condition` in this case better assign a boolean value for first if whether true or false . if the value is true then process second if condition and change the value with true of false based on condition and return this value in the last you will be okay.